# How to retrieve records from MS ACCESS database file in MFC using CRecordset::GetFieldValue

Tags: mfc, clistctrl, cdatabase, crecordset

Please, I am having problems with getfieldvalue, if I use single quotes on the first arguments, it compile without errors, but it does not display database contents, at run time it gives me; Database error: Incorrect field name or field index , if I use double quotes, it does it compile.

```
void CehilenDBDlg::OnBnClickedButtonRetrieve(){
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    CDatabase database;
    CString SqlString;
    CString strID, strName, strAge;
    CString sDriver = L"MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)";
    CString sDsn;
    CString sFile = L"C:\\users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Homebase\\Test.mdb";
    // You must change above path if it's different
    int iRec = 0;
    // Build ODBC connection string
    sDsn.Format(L"ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DSN='';DBQ=%s", sDriver, sFile);
 
    // Build ODBC connection string
    TRY{
        // Open the database
        database.Open(NULL, false, false, sDsn);
        // Allocate the recordset
        CRecordset recset(&database);
        // Build the SQL statement
        SqlString = "SELECT ID, Fname, Age " "FROM Employees";
        // Execute the query
        recset.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, SqlString, CRecordset::readOnly);
        // Reset List control if there is any data
     
        // populate Grids
        ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(m_ListControl, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);
        // Column width and heading
        m_ListControl.InsertColumn(0, L"Emp ID", LVCFMT_LEFT, -1, 0);
        m_ListControl.InsertColumn(1, L"Name", LVCFMT_LEFT, -1, 1);
        m_ListControl.InsertColumn(2, L"Age", LVCFMT_LEFT, -1, 1);
        m_ListControl.SetColumnWidth(0, 120);
        m_ListControl.SetColumnWidth(1, 200);
        m_ListControl.SetColumnWidth(2, 200);

        // Loop through each record
        while (!recset.IsEOF()) {
            // Copy each column into a variable
             // if I use double quotes I get erross
// error C2664: 'void CRecordset::GetFieldValue(short,CStringA &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [3]' to 'LPCTSTR'
//13\projects\ehilendb\ehilendbdlg.cpp(260): warning C4309: 'argument' : //truncation of constant value
            recset.GetFieldValue('ID', strID);
            recset.GetFieldValue('name', strName);
            recset.GetFieldValue('Age', strAge);
            // Insert values into the list control
                iRec = m_ListControl.InsertItem(0, strID, 0);
            m_ListControl.SetItemText(0, 1, strName);
            m_ListControl.SetItemText(0, 2, strAge);
            // goto next record
            recset.MoveNext();
        }
        // Close the database
        database.Close();
    }   CATCH(CDBException, e) {
        // If a database exception occured, show error msg
        AfxMessageBox(L"Database error: " + e->m_strError);
    }
    END_CATCH;
}

void CehilenDBDlg::ResetListControl(){

    m_ListControl.DeleteAllItems();
    int iNbrOfColumns;
    CHeaderCtrl* pHeader = (CHeaderCtrl*)m_ListControl.GetDlgItem(0);
    if (pHeader) {
        iNbrOfColumns = pHeader->GetItemCount();
    }

    for (int i = iNbrOfColumns; i >= 0; i--) {
        m_ListControl.DeleteColumn(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code as text not as images

Comment: `CString sDriver = L"MIC...` The `L` prefix indicates a wide string, which means you are compiling for Unicode. So try `recset.GetFieldValue(L"ID", strID);` instead.